# Javascript - custom list item - callback just calling last item

Tags: javascript

```
function createSimpleListItem(_holder, _text, _icon, _icon_style_class, _callback) {
    var tid = prefUUID();

    var thm = ' \
                <div class="home-list-item" > \
                    <div class="score"> \
                        <span class="{ic} {st}" /> \
                    </div> \
                    <span id="{tid}" class="text">{txt}</span> \
                </div > \
              '
        .replace("{tid}", tid)
        .replace("{ic}", _icon)
        .replace("{st}", _icon_style_class)
        .replace("{txt}", _text);

    console.log(thm);

    _holder.html(_holder.html() + thm);

    $("#" + tid).click(function () { _callback() });
}
```

I made 5 list items and added to my list (div); the passed callback just working for last list item; why !?

my "tid"s are like these:

```
ebd8ae9c-ef57-4c40-a931-16d352b674da-2222-9999999981374
266e0d1c-eb10-490e-922a-85b468d84b8d-2224-599999957718
e758f295-e545-468a-9afd-a9bbcf4cd3d0-2226-199999975506
```

## Edit

I fill my list using this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        createSimpleListItem($("#list"), jsonData[i].title, "commenting", "ic-lock",
            function () {//action
                alert();
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: I believe this has to do with the mix between jquery and "regular" html. Try building the elements with jQuery itself, it should work (I can't say why it doesn't now, it seems okay ... I'm probably missing some notions about JS itself)

Comment: Ok i test it right now :)

Comment: Combination is this section "_holder.html(_holder.html() + thm)"

Comment: Yes, @Alex you are right. i changed it to _holder.append(thm); and its working just fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with mixing jQuery with "regular" HTML manipulation.

Build the elements with jQuery itself (as you verified, `_holder.append(thm)` instead of manipulating the content through `_holder.html(_holder.html() + thm);` makes it work).

Answer (score 0):

the code it seems ok. Try adding a timeout to line where you add click listener

```
setTimeout({$("#" + tid).click(() => _callback())}, 1000);
```

Or try adding the event with js

```
document.getElementById(tid).addEventListener('click', _callback, false);
```

Comment: hi. i have this error with your first idea: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: i edited my question - maybe the problem is with my loop function